# Despliegue de aplicación hecha con Angular y Node

Tags: nodejs, angular, deployment

Estoy intentando subir una aplicación a un servidor compartido de Hostinger. El front-end está hecho con Angular y el back-end con Node. Obviamente no puedo publicar solo la carpeta dist y no consigo averiguar como publicar la aplicación completa.
Puede que sea algo muy básico pero no encuentro mucha información del tema y yo soy bastante novato a la hora de hacer deploy.
He instalado aplicaciones hechas solo con Node y otras en Angular pero nunca las dos cosas juntas.
Esta es la estructura de carpetas:

[image: estructura de carpetas]

El servicio en angular:

[image: el servicio en angular]

Endpoint:

[image: endpoint en backend]

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: te puede servir revisar la [documentación de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server), sobre **NodeJs** puedes revisar algún tutorial para subir a [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)

Comment: Debes de correr tu aplicación en un hosting que soporte node como heroku. Para eso tienes que hacer algúnas configuraciones extras.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma, en el index (src/index.html), la etiqueta `<base>`, quedaría así:

```
<base href="/">
```

Después compilaría para producción con el comando `ng build --prod` y subiría el proyecto.

Como todo en este mundo, se puede complicar, no sé qué tipo de errores se pueden producir porque yo desarrollo con Angular para proyectos locales, sin embargo puedes probar a cambiar el `href="/"` por `href="./"`, quizá sirva de algo.

Ya estando desplegado, si sigue sin funcionar, no sabría decirte, hay distintos servidores y configuraciones (Nginx, Apache, Express, IIS, etc) y cada uno tendrá su forma de trabajar.

No puedo extenderme demasiado más porque normalmente desarrollo con Angular para usarlo en Express, y mis proyectos no pasan de un servidor de desarrollo.

Comment: La aplicación funciona, pero cuando mi aplicación de angular hace peticiones http al backend me da error 404 (not found). Interpreto que cuando compilo se queda al margen mi backend ya que la distribución de carpetas es esta:
proyecto:
  /backend
  /dist
  /src
¿Es posible que tenga que hacer npm install de la parte de mi backend?

Comment: Hacia qué ruta estás haciendo la petición http? Puedes enseñar el endpoint y la ruta de la petición?

Comment: No sé cómo funciona hostinger para alojar proyectos node, pero claro, es evidente que necesitas las dependencias para servir datos. De todas formas huele a problema de rutas, ya que dices que usas Angular con Node, por lo tanto asumo que Node está sirviendo la página del directorio estático, me equivoco?

Comment: En desarrollo las rutas eran correctas. Simplemente he cambiado localhost por mi dominio. 
Perdona si la pregunta es demasiado obvia, pero tengo que instalar mi backend como un proyecto independiente o debería bastar con subir la carpeta backend?

Comment: Si tu petición era similar a esto `return this.http.post<User>('http://localhost/api/auth/login', user)` prueba a dejarlo de la siguiente forma: `return this.http.post<User>('/api/auth/login', user)`. Respecto a la pregunta de si tienes que instalar tu backend como un proyecto independiente, no sé a qué te refieres exactamente, dices de servir los endpoints desde un servidor diferente del frontend? Si es así vas a tener que configurar el middleware cors

Comment: Esta es la petición del servicio:
return this._http.post(this.url+'save-user', params, {headers: headers});
Y esta es la ruta en el backend:
router.post('/save-user', UserController.saveUser);
En un principio los headers para el cors están configurados correctamente. Los endpoints están fuera de a aplicación de angular si. Debería haber creado la carpeta backend dentro de src en el desarrollo?

Comment: Prueba a hacer una petición con postman a tu servidor desplegado, si eso no sirve debes revisar las rutas de tu backend o ver qué está pasando con el servidor de hostinger. Si funciona, prueba lo que te dije, apunta directamente al endpoint, si tu proyecto está siendo servidor por el backend debería funcionar. También deberías comprobar en las dev tools, en la pestaña network, en la petición en rojo, mira en las cabeceras y busca el request url, compárala con la url que esperabas, si es la misma, prueba a poner en el href del index la ruta de la carpeta dist, si eso no funciona... ni idea...

Comment: Se supone que el backend sirve el frontend, estoy asumiendo que tienes un servidor express que sirve una carpeta estática (/backend/dist), y que eres capaz de cargar el front sin problemas, lo normal es que la carpeta dist vaya dentro del back, no al contrario.

Comment: Lo de Postman es buena idea, gracias. 

Al final he instalado mi backend como una aplicación node independiente y la he dejado corriendo en mi servidor. El problema que tengo ahora es que las peticiones que le hago desde postman me dan error 404 (not found). No se si me da problemas las rutas o que cuando arranco la aplicación el servidor no me da puerto y me da el 3700 aquí:

var port = process.env.PORT || 3700;

Comment: Si has probado con postman a realizar una petición al puerto 3700 y responde lo más lógico es que el archivo env no lo esté cogiendo. Comprueba que ese archivo esté en la raíz y que lo hayas cargado con `require('dotenv').config()
`, después vuelve a comprobar con una petición (acuérdate de reiniciar el servidor) y si no funciona, busca en hostinger algún tipo de consola remota, tenemos que enterarnos de qué está pasando bajo el capó

Comment: También te digo, hay hostings que usan su propio ENV, por ejemplo en heroku existen las 'config vars' si mal no recuerdo. Asegúrate de que tus variables de entorno no estén siendo anuladas por hostinger, comprueba en el panel de administración si hay algo relacionado a términos como "ENV", "Config vars", "Global" o "secrets"

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esto, segun se indica solo es posible hacer un deploy de node.js en un VPS de hostinger, no en un hosting compartido.
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583661-do-you-support-node-js

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia.

Comment: Correcto. Todo estaba bien, el problema era el hosting. Es importante tenerlo en cuenta si queremos practicar con Node. Gracias!